# How can i enable the copy, cut and paste hotkeys on macOS-Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave

I use Mojave macOS 10.14. I want to use hotkey on macOS installed on VMware.
I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the Windows and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on macOS, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: I have tried to delete this post but I can't delete this post.

Comment: No, you can't once someone has answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac doesn't use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> for Paste, Copy and Cut.
It uses the left <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-key in combination with V, C and X.
The left <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-key is equivalent to the left Windows-key and the right <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-key is equivalent to the right Windows-key.
VMWare should transfer those Windows-keys to the VM where they will be interpreted as the equivalent Mac keys.
(Same thing happens if you connect a normal PC keyboard to a real Mac computer, by the way.)

Comment: VMWare is unlikely to do any automatic translation, as there is no legitimate way to run macOS in VMWare…. so there are no support additions.

Comment: @Tetsujin translation isn’t needed. Keyboard scan codes are identical between Mac-cod and Windows-keys. Simple pass through suffices.